# Dependencies issue "SpringBootServletInitializer cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm getting `SpringBootServletInitializer cannot be resolved to a type`
as far as I understand this is a dependencies issue.

While I feel comfortable writing Java code, this is my firs Application using `maven` and `spring-boot` naturally I'm clueless.

**pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>univers-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**SpringBootApplication.java:**

```
package com.thebyteguru.launcher;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class SpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I can see that the relevant `jar` files are present in the `Maven Dependencies` folder, and while `import`'ing the needed `class`'es I noticed that the `package`'es are there but they are "empty"(meaning intellisense finds the packages but not the classes inside them).

**What am I missing?**

Comment: You use an old version of Spring Boot.
You should use a more recent version to start with.

Comment: @davidxxx is there any particular reason not to use an older version?
I understand why a more resent version is better but I'm only learning to use the tools and just following the tips and bits a can find on the web.

Comment: Because Spring boot was rather unstable before the 1.5. For example, your missing class (org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
) is deprecated from a long time. You want to try to make work something that you should not use any longer ?

Comment: @davidxxx I didn't realized that the stuff I'm learning from is that old... Thank you.
Also would you mind giving me an example for the correct "`entry point` code"?

Comment: @davidxxx BTW after I changed the version to 1.5.3 the problem was solved. So thank you. I still want to know the correct way to start the App though.

Comment: You are welcome. You can start with Spring tutorial as https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/. To start the application, the `spring-boot:start` maven goal should do the job.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue.My solution is

instead of

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
```

use

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
```

Also in pom

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: Now (2.0.1-RELEASE) moved to org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

Comment: Was facing same issue...Also if you are using context,it also changed  from server_context-path to server.servlet.context-path in SB2.0

Answer (score 7):

Don't do anything new just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> in your eclipse it will add correct import to your project

Comment: And <Ctl-Shift-O> should give you `import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;` (instead of the obsolete, Spring Boot 1.x "web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer").

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem ... but I'm using Maven with Spring Boot 2.1.1.

So I needed to specify the correct parent ... *AND* change the import/class name:

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

MyApp.java:

```
...
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
// import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;  // OBSOLETE
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same course and I just set the pom like this:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

And works fine